# Records not visible in object after insert through Dataloader

Tags: object

We are inserting 1000 records in to an object through Dataloader .
The Success file shows item created for each of the 1000 records.

However , when we are querying records from the object in Dev console  , its showing only 700 records.

Any reason why ?

Comment: Most likely the visibility of the user you are using is the issue. Are you using a System Administrator profile?

Comment: @RobinDeBondt Yes , it's system administrator. And I'm seeing selective records . And there is only one record type id.

Comment: Are all the Ids returned in the success file distinct? If you've got 1000 Id's you can compare them with what the dev console is showing. That will narrow down which records are missing.

Comment: @Vanilla_Sky So you mean that if you look up the record directly in sfdc, it is showing up, just not in the dev console?

Comment: @RobinDeBondt Records are not showing up anywhere . 300 records are missing when queried in sfdc object filter as well as dev console.

Comment: @DanielBallinger Yes , we have narrowed down the ones which are missing . But my concern is why will they not be showing up in the object when there is success message for each record.

Comment: So if you put one of the Ids from the missing records directly into the URL what do you get? Access Denied. Records is Deleted, something else?

Comment: @DanielBallinger It shows Record deleted message
The record you attempted to access has been deleted. The user who deleted this record may be able to recover it from the Recycle Bin. Deleted data is stored in the Recycle Bin for 15 days.

Comment: Can you check if there is a trigger on the object that is deleting it right after the insert?

Comment: Concur above.  If the success file shows a successful insert, then something systematic deleted or merged it.  Do you have triggers or any duplicate-management systems running?  Is there any correlation to the 'deleted' records to the ones that were inserted?  What object did you load to?

Comment: It might be worth querying `ALL ROWS` to see if you can find those records in the recycle bin.

Comment: @RobinDeBondt There is currently no trigger on the object that is deletng the records. There is only trigger which is updating a field value on insert.

Comment: @HomerJ Records were loaded on to a custom object and currently there is only one on insert trigger which is populating a field. About correlation , as per initial analysis , I could see that few records with Field A= value a records are missing.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Currently there are no records in Recycle bin. (i.e no data related to the insertion)

Answer (score 1):

You commented that if you directly put the one of the missing IDs into the URL you get back a record deleted message.

> The record you attempted to access has been deleted. The user who deleted this record may be able to recover it from the Recycle Bin. Deleted data is stored in the Recycle Bin for 15 days.

That implies that someone or an automated process has deleted those records. Go to the Recycle Bin (https://yourInstanceHere.salesforce.com/search/UndeletePage and find one of the records. The columns include a Deleted By and Deletion Date.

As Adrian commented, you could also include [ALL ROWS](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL_query_all_rows.htm) at the end of your SOQL query in the dev console to see the records that are currently in the recycle bin.

As to why they were deleted, as with HomerJ's comment, do you have any form of dupe catcher configured? Check for triggers on the record type that you were inserting.

You could try inserting one or two of the problem records again and capture the debug log at the time. That would show any immediate deletion occurring. If it doesn't occur in the debug log on insertion then it will either be an asynchronous job, like a @future call, or a scheduled job. The scheduled job would most likely show up as the Deleted By user being the owner of the job.

Comment: 1. Currently there are no deletion trigger

Comment: @Vanilla_Sky Are there any scheduled or batch jobs that would delete the records?